# JavaScript cleartimeout before calling the same function

Tags: javascript, ajax

Situation:

When the user click on a cell of "#test" table it will run "update_func" every 10 seconds.

When the user click on the same cell/ another cell, another "update_func" run again and there are multiple "update_func" running every 10 seconds.

Question:

I would like to stop the previous running "update_func" before a new one start, where should I use the clearTimeout() function to avoid multiple "update_func" keep running?

I have the following script:

```
$("#test").on("click", td, function() {
        //do something..
        update_func(v1,v2,v3);
});

function update_func(v1,v2,v3){
    $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{testvalue:v1},
        success:function(data){
            $('#testbox').html(data);
        }
    }).always(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function() { update_func(v1,v2,v3); }, 10000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the timeout ID in the outer scope, assign the `setTimeout` call to it inside the `always`, and on click, clear the timeout:

```
let timeoutId;
$("#test").on("click", td, function() {
        //do something..
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        update_func(v1,v2,v3);
});

function update_func(v1,v2,v3){
    $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{testvalue:v1},
        success:function(data){
            $('#testbox').html(data);
        }
    }).always(function () {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() { update_func(v1,v2,v3); }, 10000);
    });
}
```